# Flutter - How to refresh some Page from PageView with a button?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Stateful class, and the return of build is a PageView, and each one of pages have a Scafold and a body.

What I need is, my first page have in Scafold a action Button, to refresh the entire page (or rebuild my entire class, if I can).

I try create a setState in onTap from button, and create a StreamController, but, none of them resolve my problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:plataforma_base/animations/loader.dart';
import 'package:plataforma_base/pages/home_body.dart';
import '../constantes/constantes.dart';
import 'dart:async';


class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final _pageController = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
  );

  final StreamController _stream = StreamController.broadcast();


  @override
  void dispose() {
    _stream.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _refreshPage(){
    _stream.sink.add(null);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: <Widget>[
          Scaffold(
              appBar: new AppBar(
                title: new Text(
                  "HOME",
                ),
                backgroundColor: Color(Cores.corPrincipal),
                centerTitle: true,
                actions: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.refresh,color: Colors.white,),
                      onPressed: (){
                        _refreshPage();
                      }
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              drawer: CustomDrawer(_pageController),
            body: StreamBuilder(
                initialData: HomeBody(),
                stream: _stream.stream,
                builder: (context, snapshot){
                  Dialog(
                    child: Loader(),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    insetAnimationCurve: Cubic(2, 5, 10, 3),
                    insetAnimationDuration: Duration(seconds: 30),
                  );
                  return HomeBody();
                },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
  }
}
```

If i miss some important information, please tell my to paste here.

Comment: why don't use setState to refresh the page? _stream.sink.add only rebuild the content inside your StreamBuilder

Comment: Hello, Luiz! It's usually better to say what you problem is and ask what you should do, instead of asking for a specific solution that may not be the best one. Stateful widgets exist exactly because they have a simple logic to make them rebuild, by using the `setState` method. It's probably a matter of finding the right variables on your state, rather than forcing a rebuild.

Comment: The problem is, my PageviewBuilder is in another .dart, I'm trying to use block pattern. I tryed to use setState, but my entire page is draw from a FutureBuilder, in another dart. rsrsr
Basically, I need redraw a singlechildscrollview that is created by a FutureBuilder, so, I don't have any value to use setState().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be an interesting use case. The sample code you've provided is incomplete and I'm unable to run it locally. However, I did try a similar setup in this sample app. If a Stateful widget is used as a page in a `PageView`, calling it's `setState()` should refresh the individual pages.

Here's a sample that you can check. The `FloatingActionButton` triggering the refresh action is in the Home page, while the `refresh()` function it invokes is in Page 1.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var page1 = Page1();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint('HomePage build');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: PageView(
          children: [
            page1,
            _page2(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        onPressed: () {
          debugPrint('Refresh Page 1');
          page1.getState().refresh();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _page2() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.greenAccent,
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  Page1State page1State;

  @override
  Page1State createState() {
    page1State = Page1State();
    return page1State;
  }

  getState() => page1State;
}

class Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  var refreshCount = 0;

  refresh() {
    debugPrint('Page 1 refresh');
    setState(() {
      refreshCount++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint('Page 1 build');
    return Container(
      color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Refresh clicked $refreshCount times'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Demo

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Unfortunately I don't remember how I resolved this problem. But I thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

As there is no refresh option in page controller so it is not possible directly.

I thing flutter team should provide a direct callback method for refresh.

However you can use a hack and your current page will refresh

use following code : This code will change the screen and immediately come back to current so data will change (in my case this is working )

```
  if (pageController.page == 0) {
      pageController
          .nextPage(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 40), curve: Curves.easeIn)
          .whenComplete(() => pageController.previousPage(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeIn));
    } else {
      pageController
          .previousPage(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 40), curve: Curves.easeIn)
          .whenComplete(() => pageController.nextPage(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeIn));
    }
```

Comment: the callback method for when pageController.page == 0 worked great. for other cases, i used the following code provided by GPT (and i do not know enough about coding to know if it is better or worse than the else {} block in @Mayank Sharma's answer:               setState(() {
                exerciseVideosData = newVideoData;
                _pageController.animateToPage(0,
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                    curve: Curves.easeInOut);
              });